# show form for each member on database, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, each, repeat

I have a list of members of a family for example dad, mom, son 1 and son 2, which I show in a gridview, now I want that when I press the edit button, a form is shown for each child only, yes There are 3 children, the form is repeated only 3 times and since there are no more children, the sequence ends and the parent form is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have some data - your list of family members, (parents, and children).

So, we assume a gridview, say like this:

```
    <div style="width:35%;padding:35px">

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"  >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"   HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"    HeaderText="LastName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FamilyType"  HeaderText="FamilyType"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender"      HeaderText="Gender"  />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View"  CssClass="btn"
                            OnClick="cmdView_Click"
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Family_ID") %>'
                            />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And our code to load the grid is this:

```
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM People ORDER BY Family_ID, FamilyType DESC";
        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
        GridView1.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

And I have a helper routine - this one:

```
    public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST5))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

So, now we have this:

[image]

I also added some code to "highlight" each family for ease of viewiing.

Ok, so now we have that view button on the grid.

So, lets drop in a repeater control, or even better - say a datalist control.

So, when we click a button, we load up that control, and display all the family memebers.

That will be inside of a div.

So, when we click on a row, we get the family_id, hide the grid, show the data list (our form view display of family ememembers).

So, lets drop in some markup for the family member display:

```
    <div id="EditRecord" runat="server" style="display:normal">

    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >

        <ItemTemplate>

    <div style="float:left;display: normal;border:solid 2px;padding:5px">

        <div style="float:left" class="iForm">
                <label>Family Type</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tFtype" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("FamilyType") %>' Width="140" /> <br />
                <label>First Name</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tFN" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' Width="140" /> <br />
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tLN" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("LastName") %>' Width="140" /> <br />
                <label>Gender</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tGender" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("Gender") %>' Width="140" /> <br />
                <label>City</label>

        </div>
   </div>


        </ItemTemplate>


    </asp:DataList>
    <br />

      <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn" />
      <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn" 
          style="margin-left:10px"
          OnClick="cmdCancel_Click"
          />

    </div>
    </div>
```

So, now when we click on view, we run this code:

```
    protected void cmdView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button cmdView = sender as Button;
        int FamilyID = Convert.ToInt32(cmdView.CommandArgument);
        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new
            SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM People WHERE Family_ID = @FID ORDER BY FamilyType DESC");
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@FID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = FamilyID;

        DataList1.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        DataList1.DataBind();

        // hide grid, show our data
        GridView1.Style.Add("display", "none");
        EditRecord.Style.Add("display", "normal");

    }
```

And we now get/see this:

[image]

or, if I click view on any row of the other family, the Brady bunch, then we see/get this:

[image]

Too much work for this simple post to wire up the save code, but the cancel button, to go back to grid and display it looks like this:

```
    protected void cmdCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // our view edit, show grid
        GridView1.Style.Add("display", "nomral");
        EditRecord.Style.Add("display", "none");
    }
```